# How to submit wget jobs through a bash script to condor?

Tags: bash, wget, condor

I have a problem submitting wget jobs to condor.
I can use wget to download a file from a url using command line.

```
$ wget https://wordpress.org/latest.zip
--2019-01-24 16:43:42--  https://wordpress.org/latest.zip
Resolving wordpress.org... 198.143.164.252
Connecting to wordpress.org|198.143.164.252|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 11383968 (11M) [application/zip]
Saving to: “latest.zip”

100%[======================================>] 11,383,968  --.-K/s   in 0.09s 

2019-01-24 16:43:43 (117 MB/s) - “latest.zip” saved [11383968/11383968]
```

But if I save the command to a bash script file "test.sh", like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
wget https://wordpress.org/latest.zip
```

And then submit it to condor:

```
#!/usr/bin/env condor_submit
Executable = test.sh
Universe = vanilla
output = tmp.out
error = tmp.error
Log = tmp.log
Queue 1
```

It will have error as "Connection time out."

```
--2019-01-24 16:53:50--  https://wordpress.org/latest.zip
Resolving wordpress.org... 198.143.164.252
Connecting to wordpress.org|198.143.164.252|:443... failed: Connection timed out
```

But test.sh works well from command line as follows:

```
$./test.sh
```

I changed "tesh.sh" to:

```
#!/bin/sh
wget --debug --verbose https://wordpress.org/latest.zip
```

And the output is:

```
Setting --verbose (verbose) to 1
DEBUG output created by Wget 1.12 on linux-gnu.

--2019-01-24 17:25:58--  https://wordpress.org/latest.zip
Resolving wordpress.org... 198.143.164.252
Caching wordpress.org => 198.143.164.252
Connecting to wordpress.org|198.143.164.252|:443... Closed fd 3
failed: Connection timed out.
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem is with "https": the SSL/TLS handshake is failing.

If you connect to an HTTPS site with a web browser, you use the browser's trust store (very often, this is one-in-the-same as your desktop's Windows trust store).

SUGGESTIONS:

1. Verify your "test.sh" works from the command line.
2. Modify your script to run `wget --debug --trace ...`, and check the output.
3. If only for troubleshooting purposes, try `--no-check-certificate`, too.
4. Look here for more details:

   [GNU Wget 1.18 Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/HTTPS-_0028SSL_002fTLS_0029-Options.html)

---

ADDENDUM:

If you run `wget --debug --verbose ...`, you should see something like this:

```
$ wget --debug --verbose https://wordpress.org/latest.zip
Setting --verbose (verbose) to 1
Setting --verbose (verbose) to 1
DEBUG output created by Wget 1.19.4 on linux-gnu.

Reading HSTS entries from /home/xxxxx/.wget-hsts
URI encoding = ‘UTF-8’
Converted file name 'latest.zip' (UTF-8) -> 'latest.zip' (UTF-8)
--2019-01-24 15:49:12--  https://wordpress.org/latest.zip
Resolving wordpress.org (wordpress.org)... 198.143.164.252
Caching wordpress.org => 198.143.164.252
Connecting to wordpress.org (wordpress.org)|198.143.164.252|:443... connected.
Created socket 3.
Releasing 0x000055afcdc64650 (new refcount 1).
Initiating SSL handshake.
Handshake successful; connected socket 3 to SSL handle 0x000055afcdc64750
certificate:
  subject: CN=*.wordpress.org,OU=Domain Control Validated
  issuer:  CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2,OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository/,O=GoDaddy.com\\, Inc.,L=Scottsdale,ST=Arizona,C=US
X509 certificate successfully verified and matches host wordpress.org

---request begin---
GET /latest.zip HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Wget/1.19.4 (linux-gnu)
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: identity
Host: wordpress.org
Connection: Keep-Alive
...
```

If you *DON'T* see *ANY* of this ... I'd contact your network administrator about a firewall or proxy that might be blocking your Condor app.

Comment: Thank you for your replay. I've edited my questions according to your seggestions. 1. Yes, the script works if executed from command line. 2. I added the output when using --debug 3. It still has the same error with --no-check-certificate.

Comment: The last code block in my question is all the output I got. I'll contact the network administrator. Thank you!